# Assign values to daytime NodeJs

Tags: node.js

My questions is how to efficiently assign values to a specific daytime and efficiently get the values from a daytime. The values on the y-axis go from 0-100.

For example at 6am the value is at 0 and at 12am it is 100, where it falls again to 0 at 6pm. Think of it as a curve

[image]

Comment: What do you understand as 'daytime', like 0 to 23 hours in a day? or more granular, on seconds, or even on milliseconds?

Comment: Dependent of the hour and minute. From 0-24h. 
I get the time with
var dt = new Date();
var hour=dt.getHours();
var minute=dt.getMinutes();

Comment: Hi, Dave.  I'm having trouble understanding what you are asking for.  Can you please explain more?  What does efficiency have to do with it? Is this a histogram binning problem where you have lots of data samples and want to bin your samples to the granularity of 1 minute intervals?  Are you trying to plot that curve based on an array of data?  Is your data sparse or dense?  Without more information my answer would just be "use an array".  I'm nearly certain that isn't enough information, so can you please give more details?

Answer (score 0):

For each day, I would construct an array of 1140 (24*60) values and store your data there.

Then when you have your Date object, simply get your data with:

```
var minutes = myDate.getHours() * myDate.getMinutes();
var data = myArrayForToday[minutes];
```